# Changing the view color when comparing values

Tags: swift, view, colors

I created a view to use as background and I would like to change its color when label text is greater or less than variable number. The script is okay but the color is not changing.

Thanks in advance.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var localName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var localNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var localTemp: UILabel!

@IBAction func getData(sender: AnyObject) {
    getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + localName.text! + "")
}


@IBOutlet weak var fundo: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func getWeatherData(urlString: String){
    let url = NSURL (string: urlString)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.setLabels(data!)
        })
    }

    task.resume()
}

func setLabels(weatherData: NSData) {

    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        print(json)

        //localNameLabel.text = json[("name")] as? String
        if let name = json[("name")] as? String {
            localNameLabel.text = name
        }

        if let main = json[("main")] as? NSDictionary {
            if let temp = main[("temp")] as? Double {
                //convert kelvin to celsius
                let ft = (temp - 273.15)

                let myString = ft.description

                localTemp.text = myString

                self.changeColor()

            }
        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

var number : Float
func changeColor(){

    number = 19.0

    if(Float(localTemp.text!) < number){
        fundo.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    }else{
        fundo.backgroundColor = .orangeColor()
        }
    }

}
```

}

Edited to post the entire script

Comment: what is `bg` where, do you call `changeColor`?

Comment: Are you calling this code on the main thread? Is `bg` visible? What do you mean by "script is okay" and how do you know?

Comment: @Aaron Brager: bg is visible and I said that is okay because the Xcode doesn't warn me about any error. I'm not calling this code. Do I need?

Comment: what do you mean "I'm not calling this code" ??? Of course, it's your code?!

Comment: I thought that was automatically checked because of the condition. Sorry, but I'm learning swift by myself. Anyway, forget about and thanks for your kindness, @Christian 'fuzi' Orgler

Comment: @RBB Sorry I was confused what you meant ;)

Comment: Whatever the problem is, you haven't created reproduction steps. There is no obvious problem with the code you posted. As it stands, nobody will be able to answer this question without more information.

Comment: @Aaron Brager - Nobody? For me, only those who are willing to help, as JoeBenton, for example. I beleive you guys only access this kind of posts to mark your negative vote. Maybe you feel better that way, so....feel free.

Comment: I did not leave a negative vote. JoeBenton's suggestion might help, or it might not — there's no way to know because your post has insufficient detail to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why did u define `changeColor` in `setLabels`? How is `labelFieldDidChange` suppose to call it?

Comment: @vikingosegundo It's a mistake. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vikingosegundo and sorry for not paying attention in you message before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller you need to add UITextFieldDelegate which will allow you to access methods related to your text field. The top of your view controller should look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate  //set delegate to class
```

You then need to set the delegate of your text field to self in viewDidLoad and add a target for when the text field changes:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    localTemp.delegate = self     //set delegate to this vc
    localTemp.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}
```

You can then implement this method which will run on every key press and you need to call your changeColor() method as above:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    self.changeColor()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @JoeBenton. Mainly for the whole explanation.

Comment: Give it a go and let me know if it works. If you found it helpful it would be great if you could mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Why are you using both the delegate and the target-action pattern? You only need one or the other.

Comment: @JoeBenton - I got a two error messages: "Value type UILabel has no member 'delegate'" and "has no member 'addTarget'". I didn't understand why I need to include in the action field (action: "textFieldDidChange:")

Comment: Aaron is right you don't need the delegate part. Just add the target in viewdidload and the method it runs when text changes, 'textFieldDidChange'. Is your localTemp a text field or a label??

Comment: Ohhh I misunderstood, I thought you meant when a text field changes from user input you wanted to change colour. So how/when does your label change?

Comment: I edited the original post and I included the whole script, what I had to do from the beginning. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, just seen your update. To clarify, you have a text field that does a call to get weather and you then set a label. Do you want to change colour based off this label after is updated from the weather request. If so scratch all the code that I suggested from before and simply add self.changeColor() when you set the LocalTemp label after 'localTemp.text = myString'. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the first thing that I tried. I got this error: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'changeColor'

Comment: You defined it in another method

Comment: The changeColor func is in the same file/class right?

Comment: Yes. Is in  the same file. It appears in the script end

Comment: Can you put the whole file up in your question. It might be in the same file but outside the class at the bottom. It needs to be in the same uiview controller class as the rest of the code.

Comment: Again: changeColor is defined inside another method. It won't be accessible from any other method.

Comment: Looks like you've put changeColor function inside the  setLabels function by mistake. Move it outside of this function but still inside your view controller class

Comment: I did it. Thanks you guys: JoeBenton and vikingosegundo. It works now! I learned so much. In the next time I'll post the whole script instead of parts.